# About object types in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am creating a small inventory system and equipment, here I define the objects in the interface.

```
// Interface for player obj
interface EquipmentModels {
    rightHand : Weapon | boolean;
    leftHand  : Shield | boolean;
}
```

This is used to define parameters on equipment objects, in the Player class.

```
interface Weapon {
    id         : string; // Id to return item
    name       : string; // Oficial name item
    type       : string; // Type of the item, sword, knife, staff...
    attributes : Attributes; // Object of the attributes that weapon adds to the player, while eqquiped!
    elemental  : Elemental;
}
```

But the method of the getMove class, used to return the player's current movement in combat using the main weapon (rightHand) as a parameter returns an error.

```
getMove = () => {
    const _player = variables().player;
    const _equipments = _player.equipments.rightHand;

    if (_equipments instanceof Weapon) {
        _player.myCurMovement = {
            type    : _player.equipments.rightHand.type,
            name    : _player.equipments.rightHand.name,
            element : _player.equipments.rightHand.elemental.element,
            damage  : _player.equipments.rightHand.elemental.damage(),
            setEffect() {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Type, name and elementa return *Property 'elemental' does not exist on type 'boolean | Weapon'.
Property 'elemental' does not exist on type 'false'.ts(2339)*

I thought I had already done a check to exclude the case that this is a boolean. Unless I am missing something, in theory this is correct.

Comment: Can you please quickly share with a stackblitz solution?

Comment: "*I thought I had already done a check to exclude the case that this is a boolean*" you've checked `_equipments ` but then use `_player.equipments.rightHand`. Yes, the two are the same but TS doesn't track this. You need to just use `_equipments` inside the `if` to get the benefit of the check.